# Counting datetime occurrences in a pandas series, and storing them back as a value for each date in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `datetime` column in a `Dataframe`consisting of all the days throughout the year. Every time a date occurs, I would like to count it and store the occurrence and the date. If a date is not occurring: store a zero at the given date, with the date as key.

I have tried by looping over the column and storing the values, for each date, in a `dict` but could not implement the storing of zero of said date, if it is not occurring.

Example/sample of the column:

```
Date
01 - 10 - 2021
02 - 11 - 2021
02 - 11 - 2021
02 - 11 - 2021
02 - 11 - 2021
03 - 12 - 2021
```

The expected output could be stored in a dictionary or back to the `Dataframe`, whichever one would make it easier for computation with an Apriori algorithm. Also, it would be preferred if the values could be sorted (descending) according to most occurring `datetime` count.

Example of desired output:

```
Date              Count
02 - 11 - 2021    4
01 - 10 - 2021    2
03 - 12 - 2021    1
    
01 - 11 - 2019    0
02 - 12 - 2019    0
03 - 01 - 2019    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:
Suppose the column name in your dataframe is `datetime` and the name of your dataframe is `df`:

```
df['datetime'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Comment: This doesn't address the request for the dates not occurring to also be in the dictionary with a value of zero

Comment: @CallumDA from result of this code we can conclude that occurrence of dates that doesn't include in the result, is 0.

Comment: @CallumDA in addition, according to information that @Eval denoted, he has a dataframe with a column named `datetime`. so just he want to count the occurrence of the dates! so if a date isn't in `df['datetime']`, it mean's we don't have data for that date at all.

Comment: @Shayan Yes, that is correct.To add some context: The Dataframe consist of shipment data. Whenever there is an order, a date is produced in the Dataframe, same date can occur several times - that just denotes several orders on that day.

Comment: Put it this way: OP provided example output. Does your code return the same output, or not? I think it would only return the first three lines, not the second three

Answer (score 0):

```
# adds dates with no value 
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd

#Start date and end_date
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2019-12-05")
end_date = pd.to_datetime("2021-09-15") - timedelta(days=1) #Excluding last

#List of all dates
all_date = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='d')

#Left join your main data on dates data
all_date_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':all_date})
tdf = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
tdf = pd.merge(all_date_df, tdf, on='Date', how="left")
tdf.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

The solution above answered mine question.
And because I wanted to increment all the values with one, here is that line of code:

```
tdf["Count"] = [x+1 for x in tdfp["Count"]]
```